# Android Chrome adds extra space to bottom of the page when the address bar is hidden

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I have the following CSS code:

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

body {
    background-image: url("images/background.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin: 0 0 64px;
}

#sticky {
    background-color: black;
    height: 44px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0; 
}

#test {
    width:50%;
    height: 600px;
    margin:50px auto;
    background-color:white;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

And the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $(document).on('click', '#test', function() {
              $('#test').height('300px');
         });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
     <div id="test">
          <table style="height:600px;"></table>
     </div>
     <div id="sticky"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

1) The element called `sticky` is a sticky footer

2) The element called `test` is a div that gets resized on click

If I load the page, scroll till the address bar is hidden, and then click on the `test` div, the element gets resized and an extra space (equivalent to the height of the address bar) is added below the sticky footer.

Scrolling back to show the address bar causes the page to jump quickly and the extra space gets removed.

I noticed this strange behavior only in Android Chrome (haven't tested other browsers on Android) and I tested on multiple Android devices and even the Android emulator does the same. The issue is not there when tested on iOS simulator and desktop Chrome.

Those 2 screenshots demonstrate the issue:
[image]
[image]

Is this a well known bug in Android Chrome or is it the expected behavior? Is there a solution for this annoying behavior?

Comment: use any css reset and give a try.
https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Tried it but it didn't help

Comment: I don't have this behavior on my phone. can you check it with my sample page: http://thdk.be/k/indexd.html if you have it there too?